# How to Insert a stored procedure into sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I'm trying to create an `INSERT` stored procedure in my database using Oracle SQL Developer but I can't seem to figure out what's the problem with this code;

```
create or replace procedure insert_order
as  
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE, CONDITION, STATUS, CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_EMPLOYEE_NUM)
    VALUES(1, '30/OCT/2007', 'BRANDNEW', 'ORDERD', 103, 1); 
end insert_order;
```

Can you help please?

Comment: What's the error it was throwing??

Comment: Error(4,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, and
Error(5,23): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: And table definition is? Could you try using TO_DATE('30/OCT/2007')

Answer (score 0):

The error message `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, and Error(5,23): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here` indicates that the error is with the value `'30/OCT/2007'` (line 5, column 23), since you are not using the standard format for dates.

You can try `TO_DATE('30/OCT/2007')` or `'2007-10-30'`.

Comment: Posting the solution that were added in the comments. Tagging it as community wiki following this recommendation: [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments/251598#251598).